# Print ticket from web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, printing

Hello I'm trying to print a receipt/ticket from my web site but I doesn't has a normal printer, I have an Epson TM-T88V Receipt printer so I can't use the normal `ctrl + p` or print as a normal document, how can I print using this printer? I tried with this code but seems to only works in a windows forms application not with web forms maybe the problem is that I'm trying to execute my code in a WebMethod using an ajax call.

**WebMethod and Print code**

```
[WebMethod]
public string print()
{
   try
   {
       pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Imprimir);
       return "Printing...";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
}

public void Imprimir(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   string titulo = "MyCompany";
   string direccion = "Address";
   string datos = "number             RFC: ";
   string datos2 = "description             17/05/2017 3:55 p.m.";
   PrintDocument ticket = new PrintDocument();

   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 5, 5, 410, 530);

   Font fBody = new Font("Lucida Console", 15, FontStyle.Bold);
   Font fBody1 = new Font("Lucida Console", 15, FontStyle.Regular);
   Font fBody2 = new Font("Lucida Console", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
   Font rs = new Font("Stencil", 25, FontStyle.Bold);
   Font fTType = new Font("", 150, FontStyle.Bold);
   SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

   g.DrawString(titulo, fBody, sb, 10, 120);
   g.DrawString(direccion, fBody1, sb, 10, 120);
   g.DrawString(datos, fBody1, sb, 10, 120);
   g.DrawString(datos2, fBody1, sb, 10, 120);

   g.DrawString("------------------------------", fBody1, sb, 10, 120);

   g.Dispose();

   pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;

   pd.Print();
}
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
function Imprimir() {
      CallWM('../../ws_webservice.asmx/print',
         {  },
         function (r_json) {
              bootbox.alert(r_json);
          });
}
```

I get the `Printing...` message but nothing is printed, which is my problem? Also I want to know if is possible call `Imprimir` method but sending parameters and how can I do that?

PD. I'm using C#, ASP.NET, html page and ajax.

Comment: that might work, but you need to be aware that the document will be sent from the server to the printer. the printer must be reachable from the server (shared printer on LAN, for example).

Comment: @dlatikay I was thinking that! And what if I have different computers running my website (they will have the same printer model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this part of code from `Imprimir` to `print()`:

```
   pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
   pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;

   pd.Print();
```

For more information about `PrintDocument` look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Now I get this message "No printers are installed", but the printer is properly installed and I sent a test page and everything it's ok, maybe is the problema mentioned above "the document will be sent from the server to the printer". I has the printer connected to my computer not in the server, it's possible to print in my computer with this code or I need something else?

Comment: @FranciscoFernandez WebMethod is working on server side, it's just accessable for remote invoke

Comment: Damn! Well... thanks, I will accept your answers because you help me with my current code, now I'm going to find a solution for that problem (use a printer that is not connected to my server).